# Query works too slow when there is no results

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have the following problem. My query executes for 0.0002 sec when there are entries that match entries and 0.0367 when there are none.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `main_pages_options` (
  `page_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `option_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `page_id` (`page_id`,`option_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `value` (`value`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM ;

SELECT page_id
FROM main_pages_options
  WHERE (option_id = 1 AND value = 'Test 1') 
  OR (option_id = 2 AND value = 'Test 2') 
  OR (option_id = 3 AND value = 'Test 3')
GROUP BY page_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3

SELECT page_id
FROM main_pages_options
  WHERE (option_id = 1 AND value = 'Test 7') 
  OR (option_id = 2 AND value = 'Test 2') 
  OR (option_id = 3 AND value = 'Test 3')
GROUP BY page_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

I have ~80,000 entries in main_pages_options and ~20,000 entries in main_pages.

Comment: Have you tried changing `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(page_id)`. Also, you should put an AUTOINCREMENT key on your `page_id` column.

Comment: Is it ALWAYS 3 options or will it be dynamic (different times could have more or less "option" values looking for.  Additionally, of the different option IDs, which is expected to have the LEAST number of entries.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query works too slow when there is no results. How to improve it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819730/query-works-too-slow-when-there-is-no-results-how-to-improve-it)

Comment: Edited to show two queries. Number of options will be dynamic. I can't put autoincrement on page_id(beacause it references another table) and can only create column id and put autoincrement on it but is that needed?

Comment: Tried counting page_id instead of *, - same result.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a multi-column index on `option_id` and `value`.

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `main_pages_options` (
  `page_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `option_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `page_id` (`page_id`),
  KEY `value` (`value`,`option_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;    Tried. results are the same.